# How to include corresponding css and javascript of the page in assemble layout

Tags: node.js, templates, gulp, assemble

I am using assemble to generate from html files with a common layout files. I want to include the corresponding css and javascript file with different pages. So that, for index.html, only index.css and index.js are included, and for about-us.html, only about-us.css and about-us.js are included.

Here's my respository on github https://github.com/xchitox/assemble-gulp-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already using gulp then use [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) to inject the html files with their respective dependencies based on injection tags.

```
function injectStartingTag(filepath, starttag) {

    var inject = require('gulp-inject');

    // Injects the source using relative paths
    return inject(gulp.src(filepath, {
        read: false
    }), {
        relative: true,
        starttag: '<!-- ' + starttag + ' -->'
    });
}
```

In your index.html:

```
<!--inject:index:css-->
<!--endinject-->

<!--inject:index:js-->
<!--endinject-->
```

In your about-us.html:

```
<!--inject:about-us:css-->
<!--endinject-->

<!--inject:about-us:js-->
<!--endinject-->
```

Call the function above in any gulp task. You can filter with [gulp-if](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if) and call the function with the specific starttag. i.e.:

```
gulp.task('Inject', function(){

    var _if = require('gulp-if');

    var all_your_files = "**/*.*"; // obvously only add html, js, and css files

    return gulp
        .src(all_your_files)
        .pipe(_if('index.html', injectStartingTag('index.css', 'inject:index:css')))
        .pipe(_if('about-us.html', injectStartingTag('about-us.css', 'inject:about-us:css')))
        ...
        ...
        // you get the idea
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Wilmer Saint. gulp-inject fulfills my requirements. But I have used gulp-flatMap instead of gulp-if to inject relevant js and css file to different html files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper to generate the link to the assets based on the filename of the current view:

```
app.helper('filename', function() {
  // this.view is the current view being rendered
  return this.view.stem; // just get the basename without extension
});
```

Now you can use this to add the assets path in your layout:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/{{filename}}.css">
<script src="/assets/js/{{filename}}.js"></script>
```